# fatal error: 'boost/preprocessor/control/expr_iif.hpp' file not found

Tags: xcode, react-native, flipper

I have a React Native project. I recently updated to macOS Big Sur 11.3 and XCode Version 12.5 (12E262).

When I build the project in XCode I get the following error:

```
../ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/functional/Invoke.h:22:10: fatal error: 'boost/preprocessor/control/expr_iif.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/expr_iif.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

When I browse to Pods folder, `expr_iif.hpp` file exists.

I tried removing `Pods` folder, `Podfile.lock`, `.xcworkspace`. Deleted `npm cache`. Then ran `pod install`.

But no luck.

This build-time error is thrown by Flipper-RSocket and Flipper-Folly.

I can provide further details if requested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just had this issue and it happens when you have incompatible versions of Flipper pods.

This worked for me:

1. Update your `Podfile` to install Flipper like this:

```
use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.93.0', 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.6.7', 'Flipper-DoubleConversion' => '3.1.7' })
```

2. Update deployment target on both `Podfile` and `Xcode` project o `12.1` or newer:

```
platform :ios, '12.1'
```

3. Remove `Podfile.lock`
4. `pod install --repo-update`
5. Close and re-open the Xcode project

You may also try fixing permissions if the above is not enough for you:

```
chmod -R 755 ios/Pods/boost-for-react-native
```

The error went away after this.

Answer (score 1):

It completely removes Flipper, but here's a workaround I used

- disabled Flipper in PodFile (as explained in an answer here: [React Native Project is not running on iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346902/react-native-project-is-not-running-on-ios-simulator))
- deleted Pods directory
- re-ran npx pod-install
- started the application (npx react-native run-ios)

Comment: No luck. I had to reinstall xcode-select to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving him the precise version I used the next line:

use_flipper!

Put it in Podfile and run: pod install --repo-update.

It worked for me!