# React Native Project is not running on iOS Simulator using Apple M1 chip

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native-ios, build-error, apple-m1

I am not new to React Native, have been working on this for a while, but the issue which I am facing right now is pretty much new. I am fed up with this problem. The problem I am facing is, **I cannot run the app on the iOS simualator**. I have tried almost every way to solve this, but could not.

**My Trials:**

1. Removing `Pods` and `Podfile.lock` and then doing `pod install` and `react-native` `run-ios`
2. removed `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and then `Pods`, `Podfile.lock` and then doing `npm install` -> `pod install` -> `react-native run-ios`
3. Opening Xcode, cleaning the Build, and then `react-native run-ios`
4. Running `react-native start --reset-cache` and then `react-native run-ios`
5. Doing `pod update` and then `react-native run-ios`

It is still failing, and it throws me a lot of error on the console. I am confused and horrified with this situation. Till morning every thing was working fine, but now nothing works

Error I get:

```
I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsi -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsiexecutor -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsinspector -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-perflogger -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-runtimeexecutor -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/ReactCommon -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Yoga -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/boost-for-react-native -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/DoubleConversion -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/React-Core -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React/React-Core.modulemap -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/yoga/Yoga.modulemap -DFOLLY_NO_CONFIG -DFOLLY_MOBILE\=1 -DFOLLY_USE_LIBCPP\=1 -Wno-comma -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-documentation -include /Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/ReactCommon/ReactCommon-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModuleUtils.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModuleUtils.dia -c /Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/nativemodule/core/ReactCommon/TurboModuleUtils.cpp -o /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModuleUtils.o

Libtool /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/libYogaKit.a normal (in target 'YogaKit' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET\=10.0
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only x86_64 -D -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk -L/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit -filelist /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/YogaKit.LinkFileList -dependency_info /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/YogaKit_libtool_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/libYogaKit.a

CompileC /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModulePerfLogger.o /Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/nativemodule/core/ReactCommon/TurboModulePerfLogger.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'ReactCommon' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -target x86_64-apple-ios10.0-simulator -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=c++14 -stdlib\=libc++ -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG\=1 -DDEBUG\=1 -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -index-store-path /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/ReactCommon-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/ReactCommon-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/ReactCommon-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/ReactCommon-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon/include -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Private -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/ReactCommon -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/DoubleConversion -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-callinvoker -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-cxxreact -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsi -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsiexecutor -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsinspector -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-perflogger -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-runtimeexecutor -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/ReactCommon -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Yoga -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/boost-for-react-native -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/DoubleConversion -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/React-Core -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React/React-Core.modulemap -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/yoga/Yoga.modulemap -DFOLLY_NO_CONFIG -DFOLLY_MOBILE\=1 -DFOLLY_USE_LIBCPP\=1 -Wno-comma -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-documentation -include /Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/ReactCommon/ReactCommon-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModulePerfLogger.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModulePerfLogger.dia -c /Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/nativemodule/core/ReactCommon/TurboModulePerfLogger.cpp -o /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModulePerfLogger.o

CompileC /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModuleBinding.o /Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/nativemodule/core/ReactCommon/TurboModuleBinding.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'ReactCommon' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -target x86_64-apple-ios10.0-simulator -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=c++14 -stdlib\=libc++ -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG\=1 -DDEBUG\=1 -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -index-store-path /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/ReactCommon-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/ReactCommon-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/ReactCommon-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/ReactCommon-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon/include -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Private -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/ReactCommon -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/DoubleConversion -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-callinvoker -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-cxxreact -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsi -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsiexecutor -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsinspector -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-perflogger -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-runtimeexecutor -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/ReactCommon -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Yoga -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/boost-for-react-native -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/DoubleConversion -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/React-Core -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React/React-Core.modulemap -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/yoga/Yoga.modulemap -DFOLLY_NO_CONFIG -DFOLLY_MOBILE\=1 -DFOLLY_USE_LIBCPP\=1 -Wno-comma -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-documentation -include /Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/ReactCommon/ReactCommon-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModuleBinding.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModuleBinding.dia -c /Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/nativemodule/core/ReactCommon/TurboModuleBinding.cpp -o /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModuleBinding.o

CompileC /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModule.o /Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/nativemodule/core/ReactCommon/TurboModule.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'ReactCommon' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -target x86_64-apple-ios10.0-simulator -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=c++14 -stdlib\=libc++ -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG\=1 -DDEBUG\=1 -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.5.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -index-store-path /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/ReactCommon-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/ReactCommon-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/ReactCommon-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/ReactCommon-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon/include -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Private -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/ReactCommon -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/DoubleConversion -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-callinvoker -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-cxxreact -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsi -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsiexecutor -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsinspector -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-perflogger -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-runtimeexecutor -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/ReactCommon -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Yoga -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/boost-for-react-native -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/DoubleConversion -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/React-Core -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React/React-Core.modulemap -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/yoga/Yoga.modulemap -DFOLLY_NO_CONFIG -DFOLLY_MOBILE\=1 -DFOLLY_USE_LIBCPP\=1 -Wno-comma -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-documentation -include /Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/ReactCommon/ReactCommon-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModule.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModule.dia -c /Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/nativemodule/core/ReactCommon/TurboModule.cpp -o /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModule.o

warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the SpaceX editor. (in target 'SpaceX' from project 'SpaceX')

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FlipperRSocketResponder.o /Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperRSocketResponder.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

The last line of the error feels like the issue:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SpaceX-gxgruwmfuircbegvjpqyszccmuiz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FlipperRSocketResponder.o /Users/careerlabsdev/Documents/Projects/SpaceX/ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperRSocketResponder.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

Podfile

```swift
  use_flipper!({'Flipper' => '0.81.0'})

  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      end
    end
  end
```

I use Apple M1 Chip Macbook Air.

Comment: Try out this solution. Hope this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67340473/8013132

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to disable **Flipper** completely by going into the `ios/Podfile`, and comment `use_flipper!()` like below.

```
  # Enables Flipper.
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  # use_flipper!()
```

And if you are using `flipper_native_post_install(installer)` in this method:

```
  post_install do |installer|
    # do not use this, if you have commented #use_flipper!()
    # flipper_post_install(installer)
    # use react native installer
    react_native_post_install(installer)
  end
```

And then do this:

```
cd ios && pod install && cd .. && npm run ios
```

And everything will start working out as normal. I don't know why it was just giving problem with **Flipper**. Previously it did not happen to me, until today afternoon, everything was breaking out. So do the above, and you're sorted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are few thing u can do to encounter problem of react-native projects in M1 chip MacBook.

YogaKit.modulemap' not found

1. Try to open Xcode with Rosetta and try to build
   libpods-xxxx.a' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: x86_64.
2. pod update commanding instead of pod install
   Swift-etc related issue
3. Creating new swift file and creates bridging headers
4. Cleaning project and building
   building for ios simulator, but linking in object file built for ios, file googlemapsbase.framework/googlemapsbase' for architecture arm64
5. Targets> Build Settings > Excluded Architectures values like arm64 or without arm64 and also playing with Build active architectures

Hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

If it's urgent and you don't need to test things on Flipper, try to remove all references to Flipper in iOS side.

It would be commenting this part in `AppDelegate.m`

```
//#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
//#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
//#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
//#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
//#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
//#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>


//static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
//  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
//  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
//  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
//  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
//  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
//  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
//  [client start];
//}
```

Another thing you could try, is to clean your build, close Xcode and remove `DerivedData` folder in `Developer` folder. Then you open Xcode and try to build again.